# why weatherstack api I used returning null?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, weatherstack

**I don't understand why my weather stack api response return null in the following code. please help**

Here is my model data classes:

> CurrentWeatherResponse.kt

```
data class CurrentWeatherResponse(
        val request: Request,
        val location: Location,
        @SerializedName(value = "current")
        val currentWeatherEntry: CurrentWeatherEntry
)
```

> CurrentWeatherEntry.kt

```
data class CurrentWeatherEntry(
    @SerializedName("observation_time")
    val observationTime: String,
    val temperature: Int,
    @SerializedName("weather_code")
    val weatherCode: Int,
    @SerializedName("weather_icons")
    val weatherIcons: List<String>,
    @SerializedName("weather_descriptions")
    val weatherDescriptions: List<String>,
    @SerializedName("wind_speed")
    val windSpeed: Int,
    @SerializedName("wind_degree")
    val windDegree: Int,
    @SerializedName("wind_dir")
    val windDir: String,
    val pressure: Int,
    val precip: Int,
    val humidity: Int,
    val cloudcover: Int,
    val feelslike: Int,
    @SerializedName("uv_index")
    val uvIndex: Int,
    val visibility: Int,
    @SerializedName("is_day")
    val isDay: String
)
```

> Location.kt

```
data class Location(
    val name: String,
    val country: String,
    val region: String,
    val lat: String,
    val lon: String,
    @SerializedName("timezone_id")
    val timezoneId: String,
    val localtime: String,
    @SerializedName("localtime_epoch")
    val localtimeEpoch: Int,
    @SerializedName("utc_offset")
    val utcOffset: String
)
```

> Request.kt

```
data class Request(
    val type: String,
    val query: String,
    val language: String,
    val unit: String
)
```

Here is my WeatherStack API Service Code:

> WeatherStackApiService.kt

```
const val API_KEY= "04246030f0fc7b1efe5a28d1c1724b1e"

//http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=04246030f0fc7b1efe5a28d1c1724b1e&query=New%20York

interface WeatherStackApiService {

    @GET(value = "current")
    fun getCurrentWeatherAsync(
            @Query(value = "query") location: String
         //   @Query(value = "language") languageCode :String = "en"
    ): Deferred<CurrentWeatherResponse>

    companion object {
        operator fun invoke(): WeatherStackApiService
        {
            val requestInterceptor = Interceptor { chain ->
                val url = chain.request()
                        .url()
                        .newBuilder()
                        .addQueryParameter("key", API_KEY)
                        .build()
                val request = chain.request()
                        .newBuilder()
                        .url(url)
                        .build()
                return@Interceptor chain.proceed(request)
            }
            val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
                    .build()

            return Retrofit.Builder()
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .baseUrl("http://api.weatherstack.com/")
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build()
                    .create(WeatherStackApiService::class.java)
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the CurrentWeatherFragment file which displays the response of the weather of that place:

> CurrentWeatherFragment.kt

```
class CurrentWeatherFragment : Fragment() {

    companion object{
        fun newInstance() = CurrentWeatherFragment()
    }

    private lateinit var currentWeatherViewModel: CurrentWeatherViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        currentWeatherViewModel =
                ViewModelProvider(this).get(CurrentWeatherViewModel::class.java)

        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        val textView: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_home)
        val apiService = WeatherStackApiService()

        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            val currentWeatherResponse = apiService.getCurrentWeatherAsync("London").await()
            textView.text = currentWeatherResponse.toString()
        }
        return root
    }

}
```

**Here is the output of the app when we run that app:**
[Output ScreenShot of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlZrj.png)

**Note:**
One thing i also mentioned to you i am using free plan of the weatherstack API which does not allow me to use https subscription so I use http.....
[Https error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2z6jd.png)

Comment: Two things. I think you are missing the access key. You need to supply it when you are making request. You are current supplying `key` but the param is `access_key`. Try adding `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` if it is not already there in your Manifest. Your code seems okay otherwise.

Comment: I added  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" but  this will not work here...

Comment: @waqas093456 Try updating your `key` parameter.

Comment: @che10 I update key to access_key my then my crashes .Here is my logcat rocess: com.example.weather, PID: 5930
    com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Expected an int but was 1.7 at line 1 column 630 path $.current.precip
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$7.read(TypeAdapters.java:228)
        at

Comment: Your data model is wrong, something is coming as a decimal while you have made it an Int. That is why it is crashing now. Generate the data classes properly. Use this https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9960-json-to-kotlin-class-jsontokotlinclass-

Comment: @che10 I already used that plugin https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9960-json-to-kotlin-class-jsontokotlinclass- to convert json data into kotlin files......

Comment: Check the JSON response then. Some of it has decimal value but it is being marked as Int.

Comment: @che10 I checked all the JSON response returned and data model values all are correctly cast....as per their response

Comment: Change `precip` to Double and try again

Comment: Let me add it as an answer too and you can mark it as a correct one then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things to change mainly, they key under which you are sending your API key is wrong.
It should be `access_key` instead of `key`

```kotlin
val url = chain.request()
                        .url()
                        .newBuilder()
                        .addQueryParameter("access_key", API_KEY)
                        .build()
```

Secondly as I said your data model is a bit wrong. So you can reconfirm it. Especially change the `precip` to `Double`